# AIR File.upload() doesn't work the very first time

Tags: actionscript-3, file, air

have a strange bug in an AIR project that uploads video files to aserver. The simplified code is

```
var file:File = new File();
file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onSelect);
file.browse();


private function onSelect(e:Event):void
{
   trace(e.target.nativePath);
}
```

In my onSelect handler I get a reference to the File object (in this case my video file) and then use *File.upload()* to upload to the server url.
The very first time I browse to a file and select it, nothing happens, no error is thrown. My file *upload* method is called but then *nothing!*.
All subsequent attempts work. It's almost as if the application needs to be initialized with a first file selection. Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: I can't see file upload method in you code, so I can't say why it's not working. Is trace statement works? I never met this problem, I suppose the root of evil in other part of code not shown here.

Comment: Not sure, but from the simplified code I see only possible problem: `event.target` vs. `event.currentTarget`. In most cases you will **not** need `target` but `currentTarget`.